# Preserving 'Created By' field when appending data in ArcGIS enterprise geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, append

I am updating the schema of an enterprise geodatabase. My plan is to create an xml document of the database schema, make my changes within the xml editor, and then create a new GDB with the new schema imported. After this I will import the new data by using append.

I know that I can preserve the GlobalID value by ensuring the environmental settings are as I wish. But, I am wondering if there is a way to preserve the original automated 'Created By' and 'Created Date' fields with the user that actually created the record and date that it was actually created. In the past, all of the records were updated with 'Administrator' and the date that the records were imported.

Comment: Try disabling editor tracking before the append, then re enable after you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to preserve the editor tracking fields by disabling editor tracking. However, because ESRI changed the name of these fields since we last updated (they changed to created_user and created_date, instead of the former created_by and created_on), we discovered we also had to update the field names in order for the database to recognize as the editor track fields when we turned it back on.